# Granularity of SQL datetime

Tags: sql, t-sql, ado.net

I have a datetime column in the db and when I test setting it

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
state.LastUpdated = dateTime;
Assert.AreEqual(dateTime , state.LastUpdated);
```

I get the following error
`Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<3/2/2011 9:52:32 AM>. Actual:<3/2/2011 9:52:00 AM>.`

What's the granularity of SQL datetime and is it possible to tune it for more granularity?

Comment: Well, consider that the two provided answers got it wrong...

Comment: As it's been 10 days and @Remus hasn't posted an answer, I'm going to post the correct answer so that you can select it for posterity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server is accurate to rounded increments of 0, 3 and 7 milliseconds http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx.  You can't tune it for more granularity.

.Net DateTime is much more granular - smaller than milliseconds, it can also contain ticks. You need to keep this into account when asserting your test.

If you need more precision, you could always use a bigint in Sql Server instead of a DateTime, and store the number of ticks.  (DateTime has a constructor that accepts an Int64 number of ticks.)

Comment: That is only true though for the old `datetime`. For years now there was available `datetime2` that has up to 100 nanoseconds precision. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx

Comment: I don't know why you are talking about milliseconds or nanoseconds. The actual value stored had no seconds at all, let alone smaller time parts. Seems very much like `smalldatetime` is used there.

Comment: @Remus - Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. In that case, that would b the better option, since a tick represents 100 nanoseconds, so you could store your DateTime instance and reload it without any loss of precision.

Comment: @Remus thanks, +1! is datetime2 supported in SQL Azure as well?

Comment: @kateroch: yes, it is supported in SQL Azure http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336233.aspx

Comment: @Remus considering the comments to my Q, would you post your datetime2 suggestion as a separate answer, so i can accept it instead?

Comment: I'm not sure about this wording: 'is accurate to increments of 0, 3, 7' - this to me sounds like you could store 0, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, ... and aterwards any number you like, including primes.
Do they mean 'rounded to 0, 3, 7 ms in last place'?

Comment: @DailyFrankPeter Not sure, honestly.  The MS docs state this, for accuracy: "Rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds." I haven't cared enough to dig into it further.

Answer (score 4):

Use datetime2, which has up to 100 nanoseconds precision. [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx)

Noted by @Remus in a comment, posting it as an answer for posterity.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Datetime can represent a date down to fractions of a second,and, according to : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx : `datetime values are rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds`